# Apache Jmeter - need thread scope variables

Tags: websocket, jmeter, load-testing

I am trying to run websocket load testing and find I need access to variables defined at thread scope.

Specifically, I need to randomly generate a UUID to be used as a pseudo-user ID. Our API requires this to be passed as a parameter with each request :

send auth request with the UUID
- this will create a user account keyed on system information
wait for response
loop sending sync/initialize with UUID

The UUID is the app id. I can randomize that easily with a User Defined Variable via the UUID function, however, user defined variables are apparently calculated once at the start of the test whereas I need them to be generated at thread group scope. Is there a way to do that? If now, how can I achieve this?

In other words, I need a randomly generated UUID for each thread (acting as a user) which is accessible to each sampler in the thread group.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `Beanshell preprocessor` for the very first sampler which needs this UUID as shown below.

`vars.put("uuid", "${__UUID}");`

All other samplers in the thread group for the user/thread will have the same UUID and it can be accessed by using `${uuid}`.

Answer (score 0):

I do faced this issue during the load test, the solution is

Use epoch time (ms) and append UUI value. This is the solution because epoch time never be same , if two transactions are issued at the same time, UUI changes every time. So whenever you run the test, these values should be unique.Below is the code for reference

```
epoch Time:${__javaScript(Math.round(new Date().getTime()))}
UUID: ${__BeanShell(UUID.randomUUID().toString())}

Combination is :${__javaScript(Math.round(new Date().getTime()))}_${__BeanShell(UUID.randomUUID().toString())}
```